# How to paste string data to an edit text

Tags: android, listview, paste

this is my first ever application apart from the hello world application, so I am a complete novice. Firstly my aim to take a predefined text (which I will implement at a later stage) from a listview and paste it into a EditText view (soon to be implemented anywhere that has a textbox e.g. an SMS application). I have got the hang of the listview and how to change and edit the text however I am unable to present the selected text into a EditText I have scoured the interwebs looking for an answer but have come short. So am hoping the great community of stackoverflow can help. Below I have included all my files that I have implemented into the development of this simple application.

```
activity_main.xml
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Paste Text"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:onClick="PasteText"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pastedText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

SingleChoiceJava

```
public class SingleChoiceClass extends DialogFragment
{

    final CharSequence[] items = {"Easy","Medium","Hard"};
    String selection;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Choose Text To Paste...").setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                switch (arg1) {
                    case 0:
                        selection = (String) items[arg1];
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        selection = (String) items[arg1];
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        selection = (String) items[arg1];
                        break;
                }

            }
        }).setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"The Text You Pasted was:" +selection,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                EditText editText = (R.id.pastedText);
                editText.setText("pasted" +selection, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void PasteText(View v)
    {
    SingleChoiceClass my_dialog = new SingleChoiceClass();
        my_dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"my_dialog");


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to include the padding of the includes it make it so we have to read less lines :) Also, i'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'unable to present the selected text into a EditText' WHAT are you trying to pass it and from where?

Answer (score 0):

To pass text into and EditText, use `editText.setText();`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You're trying to access `MainActivity` `EditText` from inside a separate class `SingleChoiceClass`

Make `editText` a class variable of `MainActivity` and make your `DialogFragment` a child class of `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private EditText editText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pastedText);
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...


     public class SingleChoiceClass extends DialogFragment {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        //Edit your setPositiveButton() like below
         }).setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"The Text You Pasted was:" +selection,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Remove this line EditText editText = (R.id.pastedText);
                // this is incorrect way.
                // The correct way is in MainActivity onCreate()
                editText.setText("pasted " +selection);
            }
        });

    }
}
```